# How can I use a value from another class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, variables

I have the main function and a class, I'am trying to use an int that is in that other class in main.

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << MainInt::x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> main.hpp

```
class MainInt
{
public:
    MainInt();
    int x;
};

MainInt::MainInt()
{
    x = 1;
}
```

The way I am doing it currently doesn't feel right. I feel like `cout << MainInt::x << endl;` is just calling the variable x.

> Currently I get `error: invalid use of non-static data member 'x'`

What I need is to call **x** which is a **non-static** variable in **MainInt** such that I can output the value of x on the console.
How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You want a static member, otherwise you have to instantiate it.

Comment: ＋1 for clear problem description, minimal sample code and good formatting.

Comment: @iBug if I go `static int x` I will get `undefined reference to 'MainInt::x'`

Comment: @OnDemand You have to put a definition like `int MainInt::x = 1;` outside of the class declaration.

Comment: @iBug That question is far from being _clear_. I'd suspect the OP should read some [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282) to learn about the basics, before asking here. No mention of the compiler error, etc. ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have c++ for dummies

Comment: @OnDemand Probably not the best book to follow :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `x` is a static variable (also known as a global variable), and in this case, this should be:

```
class MainInt
{
public:
    MainInt();
    static int x;
};

// in cpp:
int MainInt::x = 1;
```

or it's a traditional variable, as it it feels like from the constructor. In that case, you need to instantiate an object:

```
MainInt variable;
cout << variable.x << endl;
```

Comment: static x doesnt work I get `undefined reference to 'MainInt::x'`

Comment: Thanks its a traditional variable the second method works

Comment: @OnDemand The first fails because you forgot this `// in cpp:
int MainInt::x = 1;` The two options are fundamentally different, they're not alternative ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Peter what's the difference with my second solution?

Comment: @john I know the first one declares x in the cpp which I didn't want and the second one instantiates a variant of the class I want, I normally use is for creating gtk widgets like `Gtk::Box boxname;` it didn't pass my mind that i was supposed to do the same thing here.

Comment: @OnDemand OK fine, but that wasn't clear from your initial 'doesn't work' comment. You wouldn't be the first person not to realise that you need to define static variables

Answer (score 1):

Using [Matthieu Brucher's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266772/matthieu-brucher) solution I did the following

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MainInt x;
    cout << x.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```